# how to check execution time when building in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have few queries:
 1. How i can calculate the execution time. When build in webpack.
 2. How i can optimize the performance.

I am using Webpack DllPlugin but unable to increase the performance in build time.

Answer (score 0):

the `performance.now` package is all about determining execution times, perfect for benchmarking.

For (2) performance is optimised in so many different ways. Also are you trying to optimise the build or performance in the browser. If the latter, then uglify! If the former, then don't uglify, it will slow the build, etc, etc.